# ¿Qué pasa con esta EXPRESION REGULAR en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Mi pregunta va a sersencilla (Me explico antes);

Estoy tratando de hacer una **validación de formulario para login** pero nunca había usado expresiones regulares.

En mi codigo tengo lo siguiente:

```
function validateUsername() {
    if (inputUsername.val().length < 3) {
        inputUsername.addClass("error");
        return false;
    } else if (inputUsername.val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        inputUsername.addClass("error");
        return false;
    } else {
        inputUsername.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Si te fijas en el **else if** **(OJO aquí)** se supone (**Y no se si lo estoy haciendo bien**) que estoy "Preguntando" algo asi como;

-Añádeme la clase "error" si resulta que en el input hay algo que no sea de la "a-z" o de la "A-Z"

**Pero** entonces me ocurre que me marca error A **NO SER QUE AGREGUE un numero en el input**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es; **Estoy escribiendo mal la expresión? ** (Gracias)

Comment: Tu expresión regular comprueba que solo haya letras de la a a la z, o de la A a la Z. Eso está correcto. Ahora relee lo que has escrito en "Añádeme la clase "error" si resulta que en el input hay algo que no sea..."... y dime, dónde le dices **no**? Porque yo lo que veo en ese `else if` es *"Añádeme la clase error si solo hay letras de a-zA-Z"*... te faltaría negar la comprobación para que funcione al revés -> `else if(!...`

Comment: @Benito-B espera, espera espera, es cierto ... Parece que el codigo funciona y lo que esta mal es como dices que no le puse un "DIFERENTE" . 

Mmm... No soy muy bueno con Javascrypt pero creo que estaba "Pensando al revés" (Tengo la lógica mal)

Comment: Como tienes puesto el angulito indica inicio de cadena, dentro del corchete significaria negación.

Comment: ¿malo para javascript? ¿porqué? Si es un string vacío compara con "" o coprueba si tiene longitud cero. Ojo antes hazle un trim si consideras vacía una cadena de espacios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplificar la lógica si en la expresión regular reemplazas `+` por los límites válidos, mínimo y máximo, por ejemplo: `{3,20}`

```js
let inputUsername = document.querySelector('#username');
inputUsername.addEventListener('change', validateUsername);

function validateUsername() {
    // Se usa !! para interpretar como booleano (falso o verdadero)
    let result = !!inputUsername.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$/);
    console.log(result);
    if(result) {
        // Quitar clase de error
    } else {
        // Agregar clase de error
    }
    return result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
```